# Getting the Correct Viewport Coordinates via getBoundingClientRect()

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, coordinates

Applying the finishing touches to an interactive infographic, I changed the alignment of the SVG object on the HTML page from left to centered. That change broke the placement of the little pop-ups that appear over each state. Here is the left-aligned version, which works correctly:

http://www.50laboratories.com/demographicclout/demographicclout-left.html

And the centered version, which places the pop-ups incorrectly:

http://www.50laboratories.com/demographicclout/demographicclout-centered.html

Here's the code that determines the pop-up location using getBoundingClientRect():

```
targetbackground = document.getElementById(selectedstate + mapyear);
targetwidth=targetbackground.getBoundingClientRect().width;
targetex = targetbackground.getBoundingClientRect().left + (targetwidth/2)+excorrection;
targetwye = targetbackground.getBoundingClientRect().top + wyecorrection;
d3.select("#datapopup").attr("transform", "translate(" + targetex + "," + targetwye + ")");
```

Apparently getBoundingClientRect() is returning the distance from the top-left corner of the browser window, not the top-left corner of the SVG viewport. How do I consistently get the correct coordinate values, that is, from the point of origin of the viewport?

Comment: Actually the pop-up locations in the centered SVG are to the right of the correct locations, not the left as you'd expect if it were a simple matter of measuring pixels from the left edge of the browser window instead of the viewport, so I'm really not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use SVG's `getBBox()` method:

```
targetbackground = document.getElementById(selectedstate + mapyear);
targetwidth = targetbackground.getBBox().width;
targetex = targetbackground.getBBox().x + (targetwidth/2) + excorrection;
targetwye = targetbackground.getBBox().y + wyecorrection;
d3.select("#datapopup").attr("transform", "translate(" + targetex + "," + targetwye + ")");
```